# How do I get the combined length of multiple children in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the below dictionary in which I want to get the length all notifications (4).

```
[
  {
        "name": "3 Bedroom Fixer Upper",
        "city": "Santa Rosa",
        "id": 1,
        "state": "CA",
        "date_added": "2/3/14",
        "completion_status": "20",
        "notifications": [
            "Quarterly Checklist",
            "Pre-Summer",
            "Annual Checklist"
        ],
        "sq_ft": 2200,
        "year_built": 1994,
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "bathrooms": 2.5,
        "lot_size": 2.5
    },
    {
        "name": "Ski Cabin",
        "city": "Tahoe",
        "id": 2,
        "state": "CA",
        "date_added": "3/3/14",
        "completion_status": "45",
        "notifications": [
            "Quarterly Checklist"
        ],
        "sq_ft": 1950,
        "year_built": 1984,
        "bedrooms": 3.5,
        "bathrooms": 2,
        "lot_size": 3
    }
];
```

I am able to get the length of a single objects notifications (example all_properties[0].notifications.length = 3) but all_properties.notifications.length does not return anything. What would the syntax be to return the length of all notifications? (4)

http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/

Sorry if I used the incorrect lingo regarding JSON dictionaries (I am new to them.)

Comment: Use a `for` loop and add up the lengths, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some functional programming with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function findSum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b.notifications.length; 
  }, 0);
}
```

and call it like `findSum(all_properties)`.

For multiple arrays in array called `arrays`:

```
var totalSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i += 1) {
  totalSum = findSum(arrays[i]);
}
```

Comment: what if there were to be more than 1 array? So array a,b, n+ ?

Would I then use a for loop? Thanks @minko

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Array's reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function

```
var data = [...your data array...]
var num = data.reduce(function(a,b){
   return a+b.notifications.length;
},0);
console.log("Number of notifications:",num);
```